# Reuse cocoapod from parent project in sub project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods

I am new to cocoapod and got myself into a situation where I need to use cocoapod which is being used by the parent and the sub project. Let say my parent project is A which has a subproject B. I want to install the cocoapod for Project A and use the same cocoapod for the sub project B. Is there anyway to do that or another alternative way? The project structure cannot be changed. It has to be project A with a sub project B.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get all pods of project A

```
target 'A' do
  pod 'lalala'

  target 'B' do
    inherit! :search_paths # <-- control the inherit mode. 
    pod 'B only pod'
  end
end
```

FYR: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target
FYR: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inherit_bang

If you want to take control of the pods

```
def common_pods
  pod 'inherit_me'
end

target 'A' do
  common_pods
  pod 'lalala'
end

target 'B' do
  common_pods
  pod 'blablabla'
end
```

Comment: It creates xcworkspace for Project B instead of Project A. Project A is the main project and Project B is the library project. Project B is added as a dependency to Project A in build phases. @Horst